# CalendarAgent (CoreData) creating hundreds of errors in the console

Tags: macos, calendar, ical, console, mysql

CalendarAgent is having some kind of issue and is creating hundreds (no exaggeration) of errors in the Console. I cannot find a way to resolve it.

Functionally, the Calendar app itself works fine so this is not urgent. I would just like to fix this issue with CalendarAgent because it is spamming the Console. I just "discovered" the Console recently and would like to learn to use it to troubleshoot issues, and this seems to be the biggest issue. However, I can't find any solution online.

Here is a sample of the error description from Console:

[image]

And this is what the error log looks like:
[image]

Things I've tried to fix the problem:

- Update to the latest version of macOS (Currently on 10.12.4 (16E195))
- Update Xcode to latest version.
- Delete all internet accounts except my iCloud account, which I just disabled from syncing in calendar.
- Delete the Calendar Cache, Calendar Cache-shm, Calendar Cache-wal, and all the calendar preferences I could find, according to [these instructions](https://discussions.apple.com/message/29243789#29243789).

After this, I opened Calendar back up but it still produced errors. I checked "enable this account" for just my iCloud thinking that because it's an apple product, it should work at the very minimum. Nope. More errors in the console. Keep in mind I have no events in any of my iCloud calendars. They are empty. But I get 50+ of these errors just by refreshing the calendar...

Comment: Same problem here. I'm ready to migrate my calendar and mail usage away from the Apple products. It's keeping the fan going most of the time. (macos 10.12.5 by now.)

Comment: Did your upgrade to Sierra clear this proplem?